# Building extended properties from existing table

Tags: sql-server

I need to document metadata for the fields of multiple tables. I intend to do this by appending the tables with extended properties. The only way I've done this in the past is using the built-in stored procedure which looks like this:

```
ALTER procedure [sys].[sp_addextendedproperty]
@name sysname,
@value sql_variant          = NULL,
@level0type varchar(128)    = NULL,
@level0name sysname         = NULL,
@level1type varchar(128)    = NULL,
@level1name sysname         = NULL,
@level2type varchar(128)    = NULL,
@level2name sysname         = NULL
as

declare @ret int

if datalength(@value) > 7500
begin
    raiserror(15097,-1,-1)
    return 1
end

if @name is null
begin
    raiserror(15600,-1,-1,'sp_addextendedproperty')
    return (1)
end

execute @ret = sys.sp_validname @name
if (@ret <> 0)
begin
    raiserror(15600,-1,-1,'sp_addextendedproperty')
    return (1)
end


BEGIN TRANSACTION

begin
    EXEC %%ExtendedPropertySet().AddValue(Name = @name, Value = 
@value, Level0type = @level0type, Level0name = @level0name, Level1type = 
@level1type, Level1name = @level1name, Level2type = @level2type, 
Level2name = @level2name)
    IF @@error <> 0
    begin
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        return (1)
    end
end

COMMIT TRANSACTION
return (0)
```

The way I've done this in the past is by just passing strings to the variables:

```
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
@name=N'desc_en', 
@value=N'Sex. 1 denotes male, 2 denotes female.' , 
@level0type=N'SCHEMA',
@level0name=N'dbo', 
@level1type=N'TABLE',
@level1name=N'MyTable', 
@level2type=N'COLUMN',
@level2name=N'sex'
GO
```

But now that I have to do this for multiple tables (and ideally write some re-usable procedure), I'm attempting to write a function that takes dynamic (i.e. SELECT) arguments.

For instance, take the following tables. The first has a couple of fields that need extended properties, whereas the other table has two fields containing that information:

```
dbo.users:
id | name | sex | year 
-------------------------
 1 | 'john' | 1  | 2019 
 2 | 'jane' | 2  | 2019 

dbo.metadata:
id | property_en | desc_en
-------------------------
 1 | sex         | Sex. 1 denotes male, 2 denotes female
 2 | year        | The year of the event record

desired ep:

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
@name=N'desc_en', 
@value=N'Sex. 1 denotes male, 2 denotes female' , 
@level0type=N'SCHEMA',
@level0name=N'dbo', 
@level1type=N'TABLE',
@level1name=N'users', 
@level2type=N'COLUMN',
@level2name=N'sex'
```

Any suggestions to derive EPs directly from a source and metadata table like that as an iteration? The first set of arguments have to come from the source table itself (i.e., information about the schema, table name and column name), whereas the second from the metadata table itself (i.e. property_en and desc_en).

Essentially, the first table (t1) provides:
@level0name
@level1name

And t2:
@name
@value

And the join is on @level2name, in other words where t1.clmns.name = t2.property_en

Comment: Your metadata is missing some critical pieces of information. Like the schema, table name etc...you couldn't possibly create an extended property with just the metadata you posted. You would have to know those additional pieces.

Comment: Right. The thing is, those metadata rows are for general items that might be used in multiple tables. The only way to also include specifically which field those metadata rows refer to would be to have a row for 'year' for every conceivable table that uses 'year' as a column. Which is why I wondered whether it is possible to have the first set of arguments from the source table (i.e. SELECT schema_name(), tbl.name, clmns.name)  and the metadata info from the second table (SELECT property_en, desc_en) where column name == property_en

Comment: Oh I think I get what you are asking. You want to find any column in your database with the name in the property_en column? You would have to use dynamic sql for this. You could leverage sys.columns and build a whole series of procedure calls which would work.

Comment: Indeed, @SeanLange :) That's my weekend task!

Comment: Your new sample data is a little confusing. What is the name column in the first table? Is that supposed to be the table name you want to add extended properties too? I don't understand how those two tables are related here at all.

Comment: Oh wait.....gosh this is a confusing way to share the info. I think that what you are saying is that table1 is the table you want to add these too and table 2 has the properties of the EP you want to add? But how do you know from table 2 what table you want to add the EP to? Simply adding the table name to your second table and this is simple.

Comment: Apologies -- updated the main body for clarification!

Comment: OK so really the users table here is just an example of a table you want to add these EPs to right? There may be other tables that have columns with either or both of those names and you still want to add the EP to them right?

Comment: Yep, exactly. There might be 30 tables that all have time series data stored as either timedate or (year, month) fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go. Dynamic sql like this is a bit tricky if you haven't done it very much. In essence I am just using the system tables to get the information needed based on the data in your metadata table. Then we just build up a big sql string with a bunch of stored proc calls in it. Finally we just fire it off to run.

Please note, this will find any column that matches in any table based on the name in metadata. If you need to refine that for something like only tables with both columns or something you will need to adjust this a little bit.

```
create table metadata
(
    id int
    , property_en sysname 
    , desc_en varchar(500) 
)

insert metadata values
(1, 'sex', 'Sex. 1 denotes male, 2 denotes female')
, (2, 'year', 'The year of the event record')

declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N''' + d.property_en + ''', @value=N''' + d.desc_en + ''', @level0type=N''SCHEMA'', @level0name=N''' + s.name + ''', @level1type=N''TABLE'', @level1name=N''' + t.name + ''', @level2type=N''COLUMN'', @level2name=N''' + d.property_en + ''';'
from metadata d
join sys.columns c on c.name = d.property_en
join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id
join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id

select @SQL
--once you are comfortable that the dynamic sql works uncomment the line below.
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Looks brilliant Sean! Will try to run it first thing tomorrow morning. One thing that occurs to me though, is that I wonder if this will create duplicate EPs if the @SQL is run more than once? I don't think EPs have any kind of identifier, but if every EP is derived from the metadata table, the script can just begin by deleting all existing EPs... Anyway, great work and thank you for sharing your expertise on this.

Comment: Sure they can be identified. Look at sys.extended_properties. The major_id column is the object_id of the object for that extended property and the name column is the name of the property. As long as the name is unique you are good to go.

Comment: works perfectly! The issue of duplicate XPs is irrelevant as the name of an XP has to be unique. In other words, the query returns a bunch of errors if you run it twice. Provided that every XP derives from a controlled method like a metadata table, your script can just be preceded by an sp_dropextended_property script to clear XPs in case metadata definitions change. Thanks a lot for your time Sean!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an 'instead of' trigger based mechanism based on prior work by Cade Roux and "Phil Factor" (credits in the comments)

https://github.com/phrrngtn/rule4/blob/main/sql/extended_properties.sql

This creates some views `RULE4.extended_property` and `RULE4.extended_property_aux` that you can treat as *normal* table and insert/update/delete extended properties. The instead of trigger proxies this onto calls to the corresponding extended properties sproc.